# Algorithm for the Queen piece chessboard movement?

Tags: java, algorithm

So my chessboard grid is a bit different than others. The rows start from bottom to top, so like 1 to 8 from bottom. and columns are from A to H, basically a 8 by 8 grid. Now getting straight into the point, I'm not sure how I would make an algorithm that would allow the Queen piece to attack a position, which is "X". So if i make this input

**A SAMPLE INPUT OF MY PROGRAM**

```
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . B X K . . R 
. . N . . . . . 
. Q . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . .
```

how can I Incorporate blocking? like although there is "N" which is the knight piece. So overall basically how would i make an algorithm that where ever is the queen in any point on the grid would be able to attack the target("X")?

Edit(UPDATED) : I found out how to do it but when i try to, it only moves by one square why is that?

**A SAMPLE OUT OF MY ALGORITHM FOR QUEEN**

```
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
Q . Q . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
Q . Q . . . . .
```

**SOURCE CODE**

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    class chessMovesz
    {
      //MAIN CODE AT THE VERY BOTTOM OF THE CLASS
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

      private String[][] grid = new String[8][8];

      private String king,queen,rook,bishop,knight,target;

      public void getPieces(){


  System.out.println("Hello Guest00129, Welcome to Chess.");
  System.out.println("In order to play this game, input pieces like below(cap;atilaized)");
  System.out.println("Rook at column c and at row 5 then: Rc5");

  System.out.println("Please enter a position for Rook");
  rook = sc.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Please enter a position for King");
  king = sc.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Please enter a position for Queen");
  queen = sc.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Please enter a position for Bishop");
  bishop = sc.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Please enter a position for Knight");
  knight = sc.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Please enter a position for Target(X) to move the peices to that position");
  target = sc.nextLine();
  }
  public void printGrid(){      
        for(int row = 0; row <grid.length; row++){
      for (int column = 0;column <grid[row].length; column++){
        grid[row][column] = ".";
      }
  }    
   grid[7-rook.charAt(2)+49][(int)rook.charAt(1)-97] = "R";
   grid[7-bishop.charAt(2)+49][(int)bishop.charAt(1)-97] = "B";
   grid[7-queen.charAt(2)+49][(int)queen.charAt(1)-97] = "Q";
   grid[7-king.charAt(2)+49][(int)king.charAt(1)-97] = "K";
   grid[7-knight.charAt(2)+49][(int)knight.charAt(1)-97] = "N";
   grid[7-target.charAt(2)+49][(int)target.charAt(1)-97] = "X";



        for(int row = 0; row <grid.length; row++){
      for (int column = 0;column <grid[row].length; column++){
          System.out.printf("%2s",grid[row][column] + " ");

      }
      System.out.println();
  }

  }   



     public void movePosition(){



    for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++){
      for(int column = 0; column < grid[row].length; column++){


        grid[row][column] = ".";

        //south east  diaognal
        grid[7-queen.charAt(2)+49 +1][(int)queen.charAt(1)-97 +1 ] = "Q";

        //North West diagonal
        grid[7-queen.charAt(2)+49 -1][(int)queen.charAt(1)-97 -1 ] = "Q";

        //North East diagonal
        grid[7-queen.charAt(2)+49 -1][(int)queen.charAt(1)-97 +1 ] = "Q";

        //South West Diagonal
        grid[7-queen.charAt(2)+49 +1][(int)queen.charAt(1)-97 -1 ] = "Q";


   System.out.printf("%2s",grid[row][column] + " ");
      }


      System.out.println();

    }
  }





      public void readChessPositions(){
      }
      //the file created from the method above read it print the grid here like printout here and show the possible
      //positons that can attack 
      public void chessOutput(){
      }
      //method that prints the grid with the positiosn showed in the outputfile of chess moves
      //print all empty spaces with dot(.) and the postiions
      public static void main (String[] args){
        chessMovesz test1 = new chessMovesz();
        test1.getPieces();
        test1.printGrid();
        System.out.println("");
        test1.movePosition();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking, "How to I figure out where to move the queen so she is attacking X?"?

Comment: I think he's asking how to calculate which squares the Queen can attack X from(?)

Comment: Basically you can consider X to be a Queen piece.  Any square a queen at X could move to would be a square that a queen could attack X from.  I think this idea works for all chess pieces except pawns, which don't have symmetrical moves (pawns move only in one direction).

Comment: Guy yes what i mean is ""How to I figure out where to move the queen so she is attacking X.", basically if queen was at a different location(choosen by the user input) and same as (Target "X") how can I if queen can attack the target ?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp read what i commented.

Comment: @ban-geoengineering read what i commented

Comment: @markspace read what i commented above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly (see my comment, above), my advice would be to work out the algorithm for the Rook/Castle first - ie, it needs to be on same row or column as the Queen with no pieces in between. Then add another, similar, rule to take care of the diagonals.

Alternatively, you could work out all the positions that the Queen is able to move to. And then see if X is one of them.

**Update (re comments, below)**

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 G1 H1
A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2 G2 H2
A3 B3 C3 D3 E3 F3 G3 H3
A4 B4 C4 D4 E4 F4 G4 H4
A5 B5 C5 D5 E5 F5 G5 H5
A6 B6 C6 D6 E6 F6 G6 H6
A7 B7 C7 D7 E7 F7 G7 H7
A8 B8 C8 D8 E8 F8 G8 H8
```

Comment: Yeah, what I wanted is if lets say your the user, making the input for all the pieces and u choose Queen to be at row 8 at column 1. and you chose for X at column 8 and row 2, now Queen cant go there. so my question is how would u make an algorithm that detects if there is x and moves to that position? Also ignoring Incorporate blocking.

Comment: Firstly, I would use letters for one dimension and numbers for the other - for example, A8 and H2 (from your comment) - to make it easier to discuss. Then I would create a List of all the squares the Queen can move to. So if the Queen is on A8, she can go on all the squares on column A and all the squares on row 8. (This is all ignoring blocking.) Then you would have to run a couple of loops to increment/decrement the column and row values to get the diagonal squared.  It shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Just step through it logically/methodically with a pen and paper (or chessboard!) first and work out the actual loops you'll need to implement.

Comment: Thank you so much it makes sense, and doing it on paper does make sense true , but one part i didn't get is what you mean by " I would use letters for one dimension and numbers for the other" ?

Comment: Please see the update in my answer. It's basically just to make the discussion less confusing! :-) However, in your actual code, you may find it easier to work with numbers for the x and the y directions.

Comment: I did take a look but I'm having hard time writing it. I dont even know if i need to use a for loop twice, or maybe if statement. I'm lost :(

Comment: I think you need a y-loop within an x-loop. Taking the north-east diagonal first, you would start the loops at `y = queenYPos +1` and `x = queenXPos + 1`. The upper limit of each loop would obviously be the last square on the board (`8`). So each of those x-y values you would add to your List of permissible squares. You'd then just need to do the same thing for the SE, SW and NW diagonals.

Comment: Oooh nice makes sense, but wait since I used a different way to print out the Queen and the other pieces. will that mean I have to make another variables or arrays and set them to the valeus printed? because if you can see at the main code, I did   grid[7-queen.charAt(2)+49][(int)queen.charAt(1)-97] = "Q";

Comment: What I mean is that "Q" I need to make it in another variables right? so i can use it in the loop with no problem or can i just use what i did ? will it cause issues later on?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe you could use the `Pair` class to store the x and y integers (forget the letters for the actual code). Then your output could be a `List` of `Pair`s. Re you second message, I'm not sure. You could work with an int constant that represents the Queen  (rather than "Q"). But in the loop, you'll just be using the current position of the Queen anyway, right?

Comment: Yeah you're using the current position of the queen to see if your able to move to position Target which is "X", So if you look at the very top of this topic where I have the "A SAMPLE INPUT OF MY PROGRAM" Queen is at column 2 at row 2, trying to move to position "X" which is Xd4(column 4 at row 4) ignoring Incorporating blocking.